# Syntax error on PHP file when uploaded into server

Tags: php, web-scraping, localhost, syntax-error, server

I have a PHP code that will display this error when uploaded and run in a server:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/demo1/alibaba.php on line 14
```

However, it has no error when I tried to run it using localhost..only when uploaded into server.

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init('http://www.alibaba.com/Products');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $finder->query('//h4[@class="sub-title"]');
$showDate = date("Y.m.d");
$total_A = 0;
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $sub_title = trim(explode("\n", trim($node->nodeValue))[0]) . " : " ; //error here
    $sub_no =  (int) preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', trim(explode("\n", trim($node->nodeValue))[2]));
    $total_A += $sub_no;

}
    $alibaba = number_format($total_A, 0 , '.' , ',' );
    echo $alibaba;

 ?>
```

What could be causing it?

UPDATE:

```
if($nodes->length > 0) {
foreach($nodes as $tr) {
    if($finder->evaluate('count(./td/a)', $tr) > 0) {
        foreach($finder->query('./td/a[@class="cate_menu"]', $tr) as $row) {
            $number = $finder->query('./following-sibling::text()', $row)->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $pronumber = str_replace(['(', ')'], '', $number); //error
            $c_productno = number_format( $pronumber , 0 , '.' , ',' );
            $total_T += (int) $pronumber;
        }

    }  
$tradeindia = number_format( $total_T , 0 , '.' , ',' );
```

Comment: Most likely your PHP version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use array dereferencing which is available in PHP 5.4+. Your production version apparently is PHP 5.3 or older.

```
explode("\n", trim($node->nodeValue))[0] // <-- here
explode("\n", trim($node->nodeValue))[2] // <-- here, too
```

You will need to break that into two parts. One to get the array created by `explode()` and one to get the first and third element from that array respectivly.

```
$parts = explode("\n", trim($node->nodeValue));
$sub_title = trim($parts[0]) . " : " ; 
$sub_no =  (int) preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', trim($parts[2]));
```

Comment: thx, btw i got the same error with this one too(refer above). how do i fix it?

Comment: $pronumber = str_replace(array('(', ')'), '', $number); //error